# Making Google Maps tiles of EPSG:4258 maps

Tags: gdal

I have a map image, EPSG:4258, which as I found out is within bounds: -10.67W 71.05N 31.55E 34.5S.

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -10.67 71.05 31.55 34.5 -a_srs EPSG:4258 file.png file.tif
gdalwarp -s_srs "EPSG:4258" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" file.tif file-converted.tif
gdal2tiles.py --profile=mercator -z 1-8 file-converted.tif output
```

[image]

It should cover the area of the UK, so it's a bit too north. 
At another website here's what they ended up with:

[image]

Should I use some conversion like cs2cs for the a_ullr attribute?